# Live Search inside Laravel 5 using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm transferring a project into Laravel 5. I have a live search feature inside the navbar that lists existing names in database as you type.

When I type in a letter, the url inside Ajax is called but it gives a 500 error inside network inspect.

Anyone know a solution?

**Search input:**

```
<form action="/search" class="search_form" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input type="text" name="s" class="search_keyword" id="search_keyword_id"
                           placeholder="Search the FTSE 100 & 250" required/>
                    <button type="submit" class="search_button" onclick="submitdata()">Search</button>
                    <div id="result">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**JS script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".search_keyword").keyup(function () {
        var search_keyword_value = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search_keyword=' + search_keyword_value;
        if (search_keyword_value != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/searching",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#result").live("click", function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (e.target.nodeName == "STRONG")
            $clicked = $(e.target).parent().parent();
        else if (e.target.nodeName == "SPAN")
            $clicked = $(e.target).parent();
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#search_keyword_id').val(decoded);
    });

    $(document).live("click", function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("search_keyword")) {
            $("#result").fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#search_keyword_id').click(function () {
        $("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**Routing:**

```
Route::post('/searching', 'SearchController@index');
```

**The index function inside search controller:**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{

    $search_keyword = $_POST['search_keyword'];

    $first_query = DB::table('ftse100')->select('name', 'symbol')->
    where('symbol', 'like', '%' . $search_keyword . '%')->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search_keyword . '%');

    $query = DB::table('ftse250')->select('name', 'symbol')->
    where('symbol', 'like', '%' . $search_keyword . '%')->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search_keyword . '%')
        ->union($first_query)->get();


    $bold_search_keyword = '<strong>' . $search_keyword . '</strong>';

    if ($query) {
        foreach ($query as $rows) {
            echo '<div class="show" align="left"><span class="name">' . str_ireplace
                ($search_keyword, $bold_search_keyword, $rows['name']) . '</span></div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="show" align="left">No matching records.</div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the 500 error you are getting? Turn `debug`to true to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass crsf token in the request, so refering to the manual:

You must set a meta tag :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And in your js :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error means you have a server problem, since your routing looks fine and simple this suggests its in your controller.

You can get more information from the app by turning on debugging: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration

The error might be SearchController@index is echoing content, rather than returning it (or better a view).

Laravels response class does a lot of heavy lifting after your controller (e.g. setting cookies and headers) that might cause errors if content has already been sent.

Since your html is fairly simple here I would suggest moving it to a view and passing your data to that view.

And of course use a csrf-token as Joaquin Javi has already said.