# Simple ajax search with Laravel return token mismatch

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm not familiar that much with jquery/ajax and will appreciated some help. I'm trying to make simple ajax search which make curl request and return the result. Everything works fine if I don't use ajax for the search.

This is my controller

```
function get_curl_content_tx($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}

public function getImage(Request $request)
{

$url = get_curl_content_tx('http://example.com/par?url='.$request->input('url'));
$items = json_decode($url, true);
$thumb = $items['thumbnail_url'];

    return view('getImage',compact('thumb'));
}
```

And here is the form in the blade view

```
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="getImage" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste URL.">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        @if(!empty($thumb))       
            <img src="{{ $thumb }}" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">       
        @else                                              
            <p>There are no data.</p>            
        @endif
    </div>
```

And this is what I've made for ajax and which I think isn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $('#url').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {url: url},
            success: function( msg ) {
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Currently when I press search button the error is

> TokenMismatchException

I'm using Laravel 5 and I'm not sure how to do it into laravel

Comment: You need to add `csrf_token` in post method

Comment: Okay, I've made it like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37912362/1158599 but still TokenMissmatch

Comment: Take a moment to view this question might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819418/ways-to-prevent-tokenmismatch-exception-in-ajax#44819418

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel csrf token mismatch for ajax POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to checking for the `CSRF` token as a POST parameter, the `VerifyCsrfToken middleware` will also check for the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header. You could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

With in your ajax call add this:

```
headers :
{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

and try again.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: This `X-CSRF-TOKEN` something new for me and I don't understand why is checking for this too. Will read the docs. Thanks

Comment: This token is used to protect your application from `cross-site request forgery (CSRF)` attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution.

Add meta tag in Header.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

While you also need to add this in script.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This will resolve your issue in laravel 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

you could add it one time in `ajaxSetup` and it will affect all calls to `$.ajax` or Ajax-based derivatives such as `$.get()` :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete, you must add